# Reset the state of viewpager's tab while switching between others

Tags: android

> I've a particular situation, APP has three tabs(tab "A",tab "C",tab
>   "C"). Tab "B" has 3 fragments("frag 1","frag 2","frag 3") . When I
>   select tab "B" and move to "frag 3",and select tab "A", and then again
>   return to tab "B",it displays the "frag 3"(the state from which I
>   left), What I want to achieve is, Whenever I moved out of B tab, it
>   should reset its state. I don't want any tab to preserve its state
>   while switching.

Comment: Reset the state of your B fragment whenever you're navigating to B by tabbar. You can listen tabbar action and can perform reset operation there. By the way, It is working as it should. Tabs do save states during switching in between.

Comment: Explained the question in better way.